# Expected spy unknown to have been called

Tags: jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine, and am getting this error:

`Expected spy unknown to have been called.`

What does this mean? I'm spying on a method, but am not sure what `unknown` means.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is really simple! The spy didnt have a name, so it's called "unknown" by default.

To name it, I simply did this

```
var mySpy = jasmine.createSpy("JamesBond");
```

Then it failed with something more readable!

```
Expected spy JamesBond to have been called.
```

Answer (score 0):

The "unknown" value is due to the inexistence of the name attribution for the spy.

before:
Error: Expected spy unknown.getPlans to have been called.

```
const mockPlansServiceEmpty: Spide<PlansService> = jasmine.createSpyObj(
      ['getPlans', 'separateValidFromInvalidPlans']
    );
```

after:
Error: Expected spy mockPlansEmpty.getPlans to have been called.

```
const mockPlansServiceEmpty: Spide<PlansService> = jasmine.createSpyObj(
      'mockPlansEmpty',
      ['getPlans', 'separateValidFromInvalidPlans']
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the service with promise then you can use async await in the test case.

```
 it ('should check the testAngular with error return', **fakeAsync**( () => {
        // Arrange
        let promise = Promise.reject(Error);
        testAngular.error = jasmine.createSpy();
        testAngular.yourfunctioname= jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(promise);
    
        //Act
        **await** fixture.detectChanges();
    
        // Assert
**flush()**
        expect(alertServiceSpy.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Error);
       }));
```